# Using MySQL with Wai and Warp

Tags: mysql, haskell, connection-pool

I was wondering if below is the correct convention for combining Wai with a Database pool.

What I basically do is, create a pool, partially apply a function of type `Pool -> Application` and use it to pass it to Warp's `run`. Does it look ok, or shall I refactor it?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wai
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import Database.MySQL.Simple
import Data.Pool (Pool, createPool, withResource)

newConn = connect defaultConnectInfo 
    { connectHost = "db"
    , connectUser = "root"
    , connectPassword = "secret"
    , connectDatabase = "test" }

getPool = createPool newConn close 1 10 5

app :: Pool Connection -> Application
app pool _ respond = do
    withResource pool $ \c -> query_ c "SELECT 1" :: IO [Only Int]
    respond $ responseLBS
        status200
        [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
        "Hello, Web!"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ "http://localhost:8080/"
    pool <- getPool
    run 8080 $ app $ pool
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Asking for advice on code yet to be written or implemented is off-topic for this site. See [What topics can I ask about?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for reference. Once you have written working code, you're welcome to ask a new question here and we can then help you improve it!

Comment: Updated with working, written code.

Comment: OK good, I've flagged your question to be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there isn't much to remove. The `$` after `putStrLn` and between `app` and `pool` are superfluous. You could write the last two lines `run 8080 . app <$> getPool`. I'd inline `getPool`. You may be interested in https://github.com/alevy/simple/blob/master/simple/src/Web/Simple.hs#L134 for boilerplate reduction.